# Why I cannot connect directly Arduino UNO and Xbee S2?

Tags: xbee

I'm connecting Arduino UNO to Xbee S2 Zigbee module directly, and X-CTU cannot find Xbee module via arduino. i'm not using shield, it finds with non-arduino board connecter, but not by arduino UNO board.

i checked all parameters like baud rate, etc.., wirings, and it seems no problem at all, but it keeps msg like 'reset your radio module' and even i swtiched pin 5 and GND, it doesn't works.

what i have to do?

Answer (score 1):

If you want X-CTU to see the Xbee while it's connected to the Arduino, you have to connect the Arduino's reset pin to ground. This bypasses the Arduino's MCU and allows the Arduino to act as a USB to serial adapter.

Also don't forget to connect the Arduino's Tx to the Xbee's Tx when it's connected like this, and likewise with the 2 Rx's.

Comment: thanks for the answering, so is there no way to connect PC-Arduino UNO-Xbee s2 module when arduino MCU is programmable?

or does arduino can properly programmed and active when i programmed xbee s2 module and arduino separately?

Comment: You could use an Xbee shield like this https://www.sparkfun.com/products/12847 (there are other variants), which includes a switch so that you can easily switch from Arduino-programming mode to X-CTU mode. A common option is to just use the SoftwareSerial library (I think it's automatically included in the Arduino IDE) and just use 2 other pins for communicating with the xbee, so that pins 0 and 1 are free for programming on the Arduino via USB. But with this method I think you'd still have to swap the wires back to the Rx and Tx pins (0 and 1) on the Arduino if you want X-CTU to see the xbee.